# Interpreting the decision tree table

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am having hard time understanding how to interpret the table below.

[image: Table]

It is clear that there are only 5 cases where the weather is rainy. But when I think of (Temp = Cool or Wind = Weak) I don't know which way I should follow. In my opinion the answer has to be 4/5 by just looking at it but when I apply the conditional probability formula ( P(A|B) = P(A and B) / P(B) ) I get confused since I found answer to be 4/14 instead of 4/5.

How should I approach this question?

Comment: If you assume these 14 possibilities are the only ones and are equally likely then the probability of rain is 5/14 and the probability of rain and (cool temperature or weak wind) is 4/14. So P(A and B) =4/14 and P(B)=5/14 so P(A|B)= (4/14)/(5/14) =4/5. So you can do it by counting the 4 out of 5 possibilities when it rains or use the formula and you get 4/5 either way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you restrict the selection to lines where $\textrm{ outlook = rain}$, there is indeed 4 out of 5 cases where it is cool or with weak wind, which indeed gives a probablity $\mathbb{P}\left(\{\textrm{temp=cool}\} \cup \{\textrm{wind=weak }\}| \textrm{ outlook = rain}\right) = 4/5$.

If now we want to use the conditionnal probability definition, we have $\mathbb{P}\left(\textrm{ outlook = rain}\right) = 5/14$, and $\mathbb{P}\left((\{\textrm{temp=cool}\} \cup \{\textrm{wind=weak }\})\cap \textrm{ outlook = rain})\right) = 4/14$.

Therefore, we also find $$\mathbb{P}(\{\textrm{temp=cool}\} \cup \{\textrm{wind=weak }\}| \textrm{ outlook = rain}) = \frac{\mathbb{P}\left((\{\textrm{temp=cool}\} \cup \{\textrm{wind=weak }\})\cap \textrm{ outlook = rain})\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(\textrm{ outlook = rain}\right)} = \frac{4/14}{5/14}=4/5$$.

In both cases we have a coherent result of $4/5$.

I think what happened is that you forgot to divide by the probability of rain in the second method.